# Powerapps on mobile device only shows white screen

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

I have made a powerapps application. My datasource is from a power bi dataset. If i edit the application in web powerapps i can see the data. If I save the application and open it on my powerapps app on my mobile device then it only shows a white screen. There is no Textbox or data.

I have tried it with a sharepoint list. THen the data was shown on my mobile device but my source is not excel but PowerBI Dataset.